# RavenDB HTTP error 409 (Conflict) on POST

Tags: ravendb

I am continuously getting an HTTP 409 error on every POST request I initiate with a brand new clean RavenDB installation. I have extracted build 960 on my Windows 7 64bit development workstation (which exceeds the recommended minimum system requirements). My Config is included below. I start the server by running the Start.cmd. While the server is running, I copy paste the CURL command from the RavenDB website's HTTP API documentation and run it but I get an HTTP code 409 error. I haven't found any instructions on handling this error appropriately or special instructions for explicit configuration other than setting the appropriate Anonymous access. I have also seen this same problem running the same server setup from other workstations and using other clients (Ruby rest-client gem).

CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Raven/Port" value="*"/>
    <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Data"/>
    <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
    <add key="Raven/RunInMemory" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Analyzers"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Command line client:

```
C:\dev\RavenDB> curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8080/docs -d "{ FirstName: 'Bob', LastName: 'Smith', Address: '5 Elm St' }"
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /docs HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 60
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 60 out of 60 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< Raven-Server-Build: 960
< Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 19:36:35 GMT
<
{
  "Url": "/docs",
  "ActualETag": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "ExpectedETag": "213966fe-5c42-41c4-80c1-6a73c44e77d3",
  "Error": "PUT attempted on document 'ac171c38-5428-40d5-beb6-56ea006dbcf6' using a non current etag (document deleted)"
}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Here is the error that occurs when I try to manually create a new document via the web interface.

```
Message: PUT attempted on document 'bbc8a11d-94fb-4e80-958d-4b5c74d8e8be' using a non current etag (document deleted)
Uri: /edit?mode=new&database=Default
Server Uri: unknown

-- Error Information --
Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.ConcurrencyException: PUT attempted on document 'bbc8a11d-94fb-4e80-958d-4b5c74d8e8be' using a non current etag (document deleted)
   at Raven.Client.Silverlight.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass39.<PutAsync>b__38(Task`1 task1)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Inner StackTrace: 
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.SaveDocumentCommand.SaveDocument()
   at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.SaveDocumentCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug is 960 which doesn't support POST to /docs
You need to do a PUT to /docs/[Guid.NewGuid()]